# Parallel writing and reading Bluetooth on DRVUart on keil C(ARM)

Tags: c, arm, keil, nuvoton

I'm using NuMicroTM Mini51 Series Driver: [link](https://www.nuvoton.com/export/resource-files/NuMicro%20Mini51%20Series%20Driver%20Reference%20Guide%20v1.00.001.pdf)

In the main code I'm using the same port: `UART_PORT0`for listening and sending buffers via the port,
but I'm calling them by using separate threads.
My goal is to read and write in parallel using the same port with no blocking caused by any of these methods(`DRV_UART_READ` and `DRV_UART_WRITE`) but still, when I'm trying to call both of them in parallel, the first thread(READ thread) puts the port on some sort of blocking mode, till it gets the whole buffer.

Thanks from advance.

Comment: to do not block interrupt or DMA versions of the drivers are needed. if this company does not support it you need to write your own ones

Comment: Can you elaborate? Or explain differently?

Comment: Yes. As the functions supplied are blocking it is not possible. You need to write your own not blocking versions.

Comment: Have you worked with ClarinoxBlue? from what I read just now, it might be a convenient workaround.

Comment: No - I just write what I need, not looking for the libs